# How to find an iMovie project file - Mac- iPad iMovie?

Tags: ipad, imovie

I'm trying to get an iMovie onto my iPad in an editable format and I'm told you need to paste the project file into iCloud drive. I can't seem to do this.

Any other ideas on how to get the project into my iPad?

Answer (score 2):

According to [iMore : How to move an iMovie project from your iPhone or iPad to your Mac](http://www.imore.com/how-move-imovie-project-your-iphone-or-ipad-your-mac)
you cannot transfer a project from Mac to iDevice, only from the iDevice to the Mac.

> ## Can I move projects back to my iPhone or iPad?
>
> Not at this time, sadly. You can keep working on the project file you exported—it opens in either iOS or OS X—but once you import it into iMovie on the Mac, you're stuck editing in the Mac environment.